# How to make CSS change in Angular Material Stepper?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-module, mat-stepper

I was working with Mat-Stepper on a project. This is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywp2ru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-lazy-content-example.html) of the project. I wanted to make two changes here:-

1. How can I remove the horizontal line between the steps and replace it with something else, like an arrow or something?
   [image: I want to replace this line with something else]
2. I want to highlight the label by adding shadow around it. Is that possible?
   [image]

Thanks in advance,for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your styles and change background to any you like

```
.mat-stepper-horizontal-line{border-color: transparent; position: relative;}
.mat-stepper-horizontal-line:after{content: ""; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: red; margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;}
```

Boxshadow

```
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container{box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red;}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.
What about the 2nd issue?

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks alot man! You were a great help.